# Why is it called the pull mechanism in the observer pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I can not understand why this method is called a pull mechanism.

> Push mechanism in observer

```
public void update(Observable obs, Object arg) {
    // just update status
}
```

> Pull mechanism in observer

```
public void update(Observable obs, Object arg) {
    if(arg instances AAA) {
        // update status
    }
}
```

I think that the method called pull mechanism is nothing more than a filter in the push mechanism.
If I'm right, why are you using it like that?

Comment: Please provide us with a link to the context where these examples came from. We can't explain them adequately without the context.

Comment: Does these Q&A's answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706186/push-pull-mechanism-observer-pattern, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/253398/the-observer-pattern-using-the-pulling-mechanism