# Observer pattern: observe attributes independently

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I would like to ask how I should correctly implement observer pattern when I need to achieve something like this:

```
WeatherStation[temperature, humidity ...]
```

and I need to be able to "observe" each attribute independently. So when temperature changes only temperature observers will be notified, when humidity changes only humidity subscribers will be notified.

My idea was that I would create some classes like ObservableTemperature and interface TemperatureObserver but I this way I would have to create two "classes" for each attribute.

Second option is to create only two interfaces for each attribute (something like TemperatureSource, TemperatureObserver ...) and then implement the xxxSource interface in WeatherStation class but this way it is not reusable and I would need to have in WeatherStation class a lot of arrays (same number as "observable" attributes) keeping track of observers.

Is there any better option?

EDITED:
Also it can also happen that I would have something like Display class which would subscribe to multiple attributes(not all) and still need to distinguish which one of them was updated.

Comment: Well, you could use standard/common classes and just register the observers for individual properties or if you want to make it more typesafe use generics, e.g. `ObservableProperty<Temperature>` and `PropertyObserver<Temperature>`.

Comment: This way I would need to create class for each type anyway am I right? Because for example the if two attributes would be same type (Float) I would not be able to distinguish between them. P.S. I don't think PropertyObserver<...> exists in Java, at least I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Yes, if you need the properties to be typesafe you need a class for each type. In most cases you wouldn't need that though, just register instances of the same observer interface for different properties (e.g. something like this pseudo code`getObservable("temperature").register(new Observer<Float>() { ... })`. And yes `PropertyObserver` probably doesn't exist but if you can't use any of the existing classes and interfaces you could also roll your own.

Comment: This sounds really interesting, I will probably go this way if there will not be any better solution suggested. But I still think that I would have to create those classes for attributes  even though I would not need it to be type safe because I would not be able to say when Observer<Float> was triggered by temperature and when by humidity if I am right.

Comment: Well, you'd normally register different observers on each property so if you trigger the observer on "humidity" you could assume that what you're getting is a change of humidity. To get more safety you could have a look at whether you could pass the property name as well, e.g. something like a `PropertyChangedEvent("humidity")` to listen for or a `ObservableProperty("humidity")` to subscribe to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining `temperature`, `humidity`, etc. into a class `WeatherStation` defines one domain concept. In terms of the Observer pattern, this is one subject. On the other hand, sending notifications consisting of single values would divide `WeatherStation` into multiple domain concepts and multiple subjects. Clearly there is a conflict between these two design decisions.

The GoF pattern is defined in terms of objects (not fields) as subjects. But note this does not restrict a subject from notifying different observers at different times. The pertinent section of the book begins on page 298.

> *Specifying modifications of interest explicitly.* You can improve update efficiency by extending the subject's registration interface to allow registering observers only for specific events of interest. When such an event occurs, the subject informs only those observers that have registered interest in that event. One way to support this uses the notion of **aspects** for Subject objects. To register interest in particular events, observers are attached to their subjects using
>
> ```
> void Subject::Attach(Observer*, Aspects interest);
> ```
>
> where `interest` specifies the event of interest. At notification time, the subject supplies the changed aspect to its observers as a parameter to the Update operation. For example:
>
> ```
> void Observer::Update(Subject*, Aspect& interest);
> ```

This approach enables different observers to register for different notifications from one `Subject`. Note that regardless of which aspect(s) an observer registers for, it receives the same `Subject` in the notification message. It is up to the observer to read the necessary field(s) from the `Subject`.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your reply! I will check the book, this is exactly what I needed and didn't know about.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how I should implement it in Java, I opened here one question about this problem. I would use enum for interests and then I would need to have CASE inside of Observer.update(). And there is also one thing I don't understand. Why the update method sends SUBJECT if in the book they say that observer should keep reference to subject and pull the data, the update should be only signal to do so.

Comment: The book describes both [push and pull models](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63326502/1371329) for the Observer pattern. You could use either approach to get a subject reference in the observer.

Comment: Note that my answer here is tailored to the question of avoiding additional classes or arrays for each attribute. By adding logic to the existing subject and observers, we can get by with fewer classes and collections. This answer highlights a tradeoff. In object-oriented programming, the proliferation of classes is a feature (not a bug). Adding classes and interfaces means you’ve identified and labeled more of your domain. If it was my project, I would probably add two interfaces and a collection for each observable attribute, rather than attempt to minimize the number of classes and fields.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the question wasn't "How to avoid additional classes or arrays?" but it was more like "Is it ok when I create one observer interface for each attribute?". I wasn't sure if I am not missing something and if there isn't better way how to do it. Actually I have it implemented right now with a lot of interfaces and arrays.