# Observer - specifying modifications of interest explicitly - JAVA implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198966/observer-pattern-observe-attributes-independently) how I should handle the situation when I need to inform ***observers*** only when specific attribute of ***object*** changes.

I received very nice reply with reference to [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) where is written:

> Blockquote
> Specifying modifications of interest explicitly. You can improve update efficiency by extending the subject's registration interface to allow registering observers only for specific events of interest. When such an event occurs, the subject informs only those observers that have registered interest in that event. One way to support this uses the notion of aspects for Subject objects. To register interest in particular events, observers are attached to their subjects using

`void Subject::Attach(Observer*, Aspects interest);`

> Blockquote
> where interest specifies the event of interest. At notification time, the subject supplies the changed aspect to its observers as a parameter to the Update operation. For example:

`void Observer::Update(Subject*, Aspect& interest);`

This makes sense and I would like to ask how to correctly implement this in Java. I have few ideas but I am not sure if there isn't something better.

Let's imagine I have ***subject*** class `WeatherStation[temperature, humidity, windSpeed ...]` and I have ***observer*** class `LimitedDisplay[show (shows only temperature and humidity)` and for some reason I need that the display should be able to differentiate when only temperature was changed and when only humidity was changed.

I was thinking that I could create some enum `WeatherStationInterest[TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY WIND_SPEED...]` and then have the subject interface like this:

```java
public interface WeatherStationSubject{
    registerObserver(WeatherStationObserver observer, WeatherStationInterest... interests);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Could someone confirm me that this is correct way how to do it or advice me better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to have a set of interfaces:

```
interface TemperatureListener {
    onTemperatureChange(double newTemperature);
}
interface HumidityListener {
    onHumidityChange(double newHumidity);
}
...
```

Then the registration method looks like:

```
void registerListener(Object listener)
```

And you'd implement a listener:

```
class MyListener implements TemperatureListener, HumidityListener {
...
}
```

Not necessarily better, but makes it simple to see what has actually changed, if that's important.

Comment: Hi, this is what I have suggested in the original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198966/observer-pattern-observe-attributes-independently) but for some reason GoF suggest not to do so ... (I have it implemented like this right now.)

Comment: Great minds think alike @JakubZnamenáček, although they also say that fools seldom differ :-) I should have looked at your original post.

Comment: Maybe this implementation is more difficult in C++?

Comment: Maybe, but ti would be great if someone from C++ could confirm that.

Comment: Actually I would need something like in the GoF because need to read all of the attributes of WeatherStation (not all but a lot of them) but I just need to differentiate what has changed. (Right now I am keeping the reference to WeatherStation in each observer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation with a single observer interface and multiple notifications. As commented in the previous question, I do not particularly like this solution as I prefer to name the observers with individual interfaces rather than sending a method argument; but this shows the tradeoff of fewer classes for more logic.

```
public class Main {
    enum ObservableValue {
        TEMP, HUMIDITY, WIND
    }

    interface Observer {
        void notify(ObservableValue changed);
    }

    static class LimitedDisplay implements Observer {
        @Override
        public void notify(ObservableValue changed) {
            System.out.println(changed + " has changed.");
        }
    }

    static class WeatherStation {
        private double temp;
        private double humidity;
        private double wind;

        private final Map<ObservableValue, Set<Observer>> observers = new EnumMap<>(ObservableValue.class);

        WeatherStation() {
            Arrays.stream(ObservableValue.values()).forEach(value -> observers.put(value, new HashSet<>()));
        }

        void register(Observer observer, ObservableValue... values) {
            Arrays.stream(values).forEach(value -> observers.get(value).add(observer));
        }

        void setTemp(double temp) {
            this.temp = temp;
            observers.get(TEMP).forEach(observer -> observer.notify(TEMP));
        }

        void setHumidity(double humidity) {
            this.humidity = humidity;
            observers.get(HUMIDITY).forEach(observer -> observer.notify(HUMIDITY));
        }

        void setWind(double wind) {
            this.wind = wind;
            observers.get(WIND).forEach(observer -> observer.notify(WIND));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WeatherStation ws = new WeatherStation();
        ws.register(new LimitedDisplay(), ObservableValue.values());
        ws.setTemp(1.2);
        ws.setHumidity(3.4);
        ws.setWind(5.6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would do it exactly like this but I like the "interface" version more because I don't have to have CASE inside of observer.notify. There was probably some misunderstanding in original question but I am glad that we all agreed that "interface" version is the way to go.

Comment: It may be possible to avoid branching logic by putting it directly into the enum (which is really what enums are for in Java) but I still find interfaces more straight forward.