# Observer pattern - multiple reasons to observe a Subject

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

How could we implement the observer design pattern if a `Subject` is observed for multiple reasons? For example, a weather station is observed by a object that tracks the temperature and by another object that wants to be notified when the forecasts changes.

I would like to stay as close as possible to the UML diagram of the pattern presented in the gang of four's book.

[image]

Comment: In what language? How (or whether) to implement any particular design pattern is highly language-dependent.

Comment: Perhaps they're best conceived of as different `Subject`s. But, otherwise, the `Subject` can emit an `Update` on any change whatever; the concrete `Update` that the particular `Observer` passed in can examine the new state data to decide whether that event is actually relevant to the `Observer`.

Comment: Let's say we want to implement this in java for example

Comment: If you're taking the same course as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12804925/jakub-znamen%c3%a1%c4%8dek) who asked multiple questions about observing weather stations a few weeks ago, then those answers probably fit here as well.

Comment: Thank you jaco0646, this answer is very helpfull : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233285/observer-specifying-modifications-of-interest-explicitly-java-implementation

Comment: Feel free to upvote the question and any answers that helped you.