# Using an observer design template with push or pull

Tags: oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I am learning the basics of software engineering independently.
And there's something I did not understand about the observer design template.

[image]

I have this diagram, in this diagram I marked what each part says, whether it is an observer, subject, concreteObserver or adapter.

From this chart I did not understand if it is a model of push or pull.
In my opinion it's a pull, but I'm not sure.
I think it's Pull, because we inform our Observers that there was a change, and the Observers go and check what the change was and interrogate the subject's state.

I would be happy if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the `ColourHandler` is a Subject and the `ColourSelector`s are its Observers. `Colour` itself is a simple data structure. I have no idea why it would have a `set_colour()` method. An enum would be sufficient. Adapter is a separate design pattern, unrelated to Observer.

No implementation of the `update()` method is shown; however, we can see it takes no arguments. That is a strong indication of a **pull** model: the `ColourSelector`s must query the `ColourHandler` to determine the new `Colour`. Another indication is the circular dependency between Subject and Observer. In a **push** model, the Observer needn't be coupled to the Subject.

Also see the GoF description of [push vs pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63326502/1371329).